# How to write group-by clause in Django of two tables

Tags: django, join, group-by, django-orm

I have the following two tables in MySQL database. I want to find sum of withdraw, rakeback and deposits per player and show them in django template. I get a result but each dictionary of list repeat uname from primary key.

Primary Key Table (Players)

| id | uname | fname | lname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hajra | Basit | iqbal |
| 2 | newton | Thomas | Kirk |

Foreign Key Table (Transactions)

| Id | Admin | Tran_date | tran_amount | Tran_type | Ply_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | van | 2023-05-11 | 24 | withdraw | 2 |
| 2 | musa | 2023-03-28 | 14.2563 | withdraw | 2 |
| 3 | zafar | 2014-10-14 | 25.365 | rakeback | 2 |
| 4 | Payoo | 2002-08-12 | 63.25 | deposit | 2 |
| 5 | zaman | 2023-05-01 | 14.23 | deposit | 1 |
| 6 | imran | 2023-05-02 | 25.23 | deposit | 1 |

I have tried the following query

```
data = Transaction.objects.values('uname', 'tran_type').order_by().annotate(Total=Sum('tran_amount'))
```

Expected Result

```
 <QuerySet [{'uname': 'newton', 'tran_type': 'withdraw', 'Total':
38.256299999999996, 'tran_type': 'rakeback', 'Total': 25.365, 'tran_type': 'deposit', 'Total': 63.25}, {'uname': 'hajra', 'tran_type': 'withdraw', 'Total': 0.0, 'tran_type': 'rakeback', 'Total': 0.0, 'tran_type': 'deposit', 'Total': 39.46}]
```

Or

```
<QuerySet [{'newton', 'withdraw', 38.256299999999996, 'rakeback', 25.365, 'deposit', 63.25}, {'hajra', 'withdraw', 0.0, 'rakeback', 0.0, 'deposit', 39.46}]
```